# #default_value not being displayed in form

Tags: forms

Here's a function that returns a form:

```
function myfunc($str)
{
    $form = array();
    $form['header text'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<h2>blah blah blah</h2>',
    );
    $form['new_str_value'] = array(
         '#type' => 'textfield',
         '#title' => 'New String Value',
         '#size' => 60,
         '#maxlength' => 128,
         '#required' => TRUE,
         '#default_value' => $str,
    ); 

    return $form;
}
```

The textfield displays correctly with the right size and label, but it is not populated with an initial value. Any ideas? Should I be rendering or building the form in the function before returning it, or setting the value in `$form_state` ... or something?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How is `$str` being passed to the form function?

Comment: ``myfunc`` is called via a page callback from ``hook_menu`` - it's a page argument passed in from the URL. I've simplified the actual function in this listing - but ``$str`` definitely contains a useful string by the time it is used as ``#default_value``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Drupal 7...

The signature for form functions needs to follow a strict pattern; Drupal will pass along `$form` and `$form_state` as the first two args, and anything else as subsequent args.

So assuming `$str` should be the first custom arg to the form, the signature should look like this:

```
function myfunc($form, &$form_state, $str) {
```

Comment: Thanks for this Clive. This gives me a further problem, then - if I need to call this function from ``hook_menu`` by setting ``page callback`` to ``drupal_get_form`` and ``page_arguments`` to ``array('myfunc')``, how do I now pass through the token from the URL? (The path is ``admin/config/foo/bar/%``).

Comment: That would be `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 'page arguments' => array('myfunc', 4)`, where the `4` refers to the zero-based index of the parameter in the URL, when split on the `/` char. I'm always curious whether that particular explanation will mean anything to someone who hasn't seen it before, do let me know if not ;)

Comment: Magic!! That works. BTW the explanation of where '4' comes from does make sense to me, but only because I've figured it out previously - it took me a while to work out how to set those parameter values! Best regards, MB